# R,shiny dynamic data manipulation and selecting rows according to a condition

Tags: r, shiny

I have a csv file in mongodb server. I read it in R shiny using the following snippet of code,

```
 library(shiny)
    shinyServer(

      function(input,output,session)
      {
        dataf <-eventReactive(input$load, {
              con <- mongo(collection = "recent", url = "mongodb:some url")
              mydata <- con$find()
            })
    output$variables = renderUI({
      selectInput('variables', 'Choose the device', outVar())
    })
    outVar <- reactive({      
        devices <- dataf()
        ds <- devices$`Source`
        return(unique(ds))
    })
      }
```

And dataf contains something like,

```
serial no    source target r_no
1              A      B     4
2              B      C     9
3              A      E     3
4              B      A     6
5              A      F     7
6              C      G     2
```

Now,I want to select only the rows that correspond to a particular user input that is selected by user in a drop down list button on ui.R.

Suppose user selects 'A' then I have the entire rows that have only A as the Source in it. Like,

```
serial no    source target    r_no
    1              A      B     4
    3              A      E     3
    5              A      F     7
```

My ui.R is as follows:

```
library(shiny)
library(mongolite)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

  titlePanel(title=h3()),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      uiOutput("variables"),
      br(), width = 3),
    mainPanel(uiOutput("tb"))               
  )
)
)
```

How do I accomplish this in R shiny? Please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were pretty close in outVar,

In server.R add inside shinyServer function:

```
outVar <- reactive({ 

  mongo_results <- dataf()

  output <- mongo_results[which(mongo_results[,'source'] == input$variables),]

  return(output) 

})
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Will try it out. Should it include a submit button or does the value of mongo_results change as the user changes the source variables?

Comment: I tried it and got the following error - Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)

Comment: Sorry, that was my mistake. I got the required output. Your answer worked like a charm. Thanks so much. Suppose I have to combine 2 conditions, do I use '&&' like output <- mongo_results[which(mongo_results[,'source'] == input$variables && mongo_results[,'source'] == input$variables1),] ?

Comment: Ok, Thanks a ton!